# Php mysqli remove complete row if duplicate

Tags: php, mysqli

I've never had issues with a query before but I just can't get this to work. I have 2 tables, 1 is called items_sale and the other is item_list. My form has a dropdown menu which gets all the items from the item_list.

What I need to do is block any items from that dropdown list which are already on the items_sale list + the user_id = the current user's id.

So for example I have item 2 and 5 for sale, that means that both item 2 and 5 shouldn't be shown in the dropdown menu.

I looked around and found solutions like adding DISTINCT and UNION but I can't seem to get it to delete the whole row. For instance DISTINCT just deleted 1 value and kept the other.

items_sale:
[image: items_sale]
item_list:
[image: item_list]

Comment: could you use a NOT IN subquery ? What does your current query look like ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I would do is to put all the items that the user is selling into an array, and then pull all the items from the items table where not in array.

```
<?php
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');

    $currentUser = '1234';

    $items = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM item_list WHERE item_ID NOT IN (SELECT item_id FROM items_sale WHERE user_id = '$currentUser')");
```

EDIT: Changed to subquery instead of two separate queries

Comment: I think you still need to filter your 2nd query by user_id. Because of this, you can combine the 2 queries into 1.

Comment: Thats great! I didn't know you could use NOT IN as a command, I'll be using that more often.